# Regex to find a hypen not sourrounded by charachters

Tags: c#, regex

I need help to build a regular expression to find all hyphens whose previous and next characters are not a-z and A-Z. The following are the examples in which hyphens should be found.

```
This is - test
this is -test
this is- test
this is 2- test
this is 2 -test
this is 2-2 test
```

Following is the example in which hyphen is ignored:

```
this is-test
```

So far I am able to write this:

```
(?<=[^a-z])-(?=[^a-z])
```

And this is only searching the following hyphens in the lines:

```
This is - test
this is 2- test
this is 2-2 test
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Don't you just need `(?<=[^a-zA-Z])-(?=[^a-zA-Z])` ? What if the hyphen is the first or last character? Did you mean "and" or "or"?

Comment: You need to write either "...hyphens preceded and followed by characters other than ..." or "...hyphens preceded and followed by characters other than ... , a hyphen at the beginning of the string and followed by a character other than ... and a hyphen at the end of the string preceded by a character other than ...".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, instead of using a negated class in a positive Lookahead/Lookbehind, you could use negative Lookaheads/Lookbehinds instead (unless you want to make sure that the hyphen is preceded and followed by something). Now, your pattern means:

> Match a hyphen that is not preceded by `[a-z]` ***and*** not followed
>   by `[a-z]`.

Whereas you seem to be looking for:

> Match a hyphen that is not both preceded by `[a-z]` and followed by
>   `[a-z]` at the same time.

In which case, you may use the following:

```
(?<![a-z])-|-(?![a-z])
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/Gk11bO/1).

Or if you want to keep the positive Lookarounds with negated classes:

```
(?<=[^a-z])-|-(?=[^a-z])
```

**Note:** You mentioned that you want to check for both `a-z` and `A-Z` but in your example, you only used `a-z`. To check for both, you may replace `[a-z]` with `[a-zA-Z]` in the pattern above.

Comment: I'm not sure I would interpret "and" as "or". Also don't forget about the "A-Z".

Comment: @NetMage I added an explanation. It's a little tricky because it could be "and" in both causes (or it could be "or" depending on how you make up the sentence). The examples provided by the OP, however, suggest that they're looking for the second.

Comment: I see what you mean. Still think you need "A-Z".

Comment: No. The OP's pattern requires the hyphen to be preceded and followed by characters other than a hyphen, which has implications for a hyphen at the beginning or end of the string.

Comment: @NetMage OP used "a-z" in their pattern but you're right. Added a note.

Comment: @CarySwoveland You're right. That could be what the OP intended.